# installing by_star gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Can someone shed light on how to setup by_star gem: https://rubygems.org/gems/by_star?

I ran ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/radar/by_star.git.

However, when I went to call a by_star method in one of my models from console, I got an undefined method error.

Do I need include or require statement?  Could I be missing dependent gems?  Ruby version issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you just tried 

`require 'by_star'`

Comment: @Gady: You input this either in the interactive ruby console or in the ruby file where the module is being used.